# How to get current playing song details from MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

Is there any way to get the details of current song played by [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)?

Comment: Your own MediaPlayer instance in your app or from another app?

Answer (score 15):

Just for reference, this works:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MediaPlayer extends Activity {

public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";
public static final String CMDNAME = "command";
public static final String CMDTOGGLEPAUSE = "togglepause";
public static final String CMDSTOP = "stop";
public static final String CMDPAUSE = "pause";
public static final String CMDPREVIOUS = "previous";
public static final String CMDNEXT = "next";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");

registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
String action = intent.getAction();
String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
Log.d("mIntentReceiver.onReceive ", action + " / " + cmd);
String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
Log.d("Music",artist+":"+album+":"+track);
}
};
}
```

Comment: I didn't have any luck registering for the broadcast receiver (using your code) and then playing an MP3 with the MediaPlayer - no broadcast was received !

Comment: only works for google play Music. How can i get info for other players while playing?

Answer (score 9):

There is no [documented method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for getting info on the currently playing file from a MediaPlayer instance, you'll need to make your app store that information itself in another way. If you're using a Service to keep track of your MediaPlayer instance (which I'd recommend) then this shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I can see lot of widget which shows the song details like you see in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html this widget.

Comment: Yes. And? Music widgets are designed to integrate with a certain player, and you can't make your own widget easily integrate with another media player.

Comment: OK... Then i ll create a service to keep track on Media player instance..

Thank you very much for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have your own model classes from wherein you can set and get your song title. For this and other information, see Stack Overflow question:
 [How to set the PlayList Index for Mediaplayer(ExpressionMediaPlayer:Mediaplayer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780295/how-to-set-the-playlist-index-for-mediaplayerexpressionmediaplayermediaplayer).

If you are keen to know how it is being implemented, you can get the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master) and see how they have implemented.

Answer (score -1):

I learned how to do it just now, so I don't know if it works on all versions of android yet.

```
private void getTrackInfo(Uri audioFileUri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever= new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(getRealPathFromURI(audioFileUri));
    String artist = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    String title = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

}


private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    File myFile = new File(uri.getPath().toString());
    String s = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: OP question was to retrieve the song details which is playing in MediaPlayer object. This is a different answer.