# Details of music track being played in android

Tags: android, media, android-service

Is there a service in android that can be used for getting details of a music track being played by any media player.

Comment: kindly try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616956/how-to-get-current-playing-song-details-from-mediaplayer