# how can i get song details, when user chooses a song>complete action using dialog> into my app

Tags: android

How can i get song details to play from sdcard and complete the action using my application.what are the attributes in manifest,how can i extract song details into my applicatin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<activity android:label="Name" android:name=".activity.ActivityName" android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Try the above to make your application show up in the default listing when the dialog appears. Also refer to *[How to get current playing song details from MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616956/how-to-get-current-playing-song-details-from-mediaplayer)* for getting the current playing song details.