# How do you access "elapsed time" of currently playing Android song?

Tags: android, media-player

I'm using the code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616956/how-to-get-current-playing-song-details-from-mediaplayer) in order to get track title, artist, and album for the currently playing song in the Android music player (or Play Music).

That is, I'd like to be able to access how far into the current song you are.

I'm looking at this bit from the aforementioned SO question:

```
String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
```

It seems to me that I should be able to access other metrics in a similar way, but I can't find a way to look at what String values are valid keys for the `intent.getStringExtra()` method.

I'm a noob to the android development scene, so forgive me my beginnerness! Am I on the right track?

**[EDIT]:** I was able to find the Intent when debugging; are these values being stored in that `mExtras` Hashmap? If so, I can see that such values as `duration` are available, though elapsed time is not.

Comment: are you initiating the media player instance to play the file ?

Comment: Nope, I'm just trying to access media that is already playing in the media-player.

Comment: Yes the values come from the `mExtras` map

Comment: In that case, would I be correct in assuming that, because nothing refers to Elapsed Time in that map, this is inaccessible data...?

Comment: how about looping through all the keys inside the extra bundle ?

Comment: From what I could see in debugging mode, there isn't anything in there besides artist, album, title, duration, and some other internal-use-only info like artist-id, list-id, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the solution:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

Long elapsedtime = extras.getLong("position");

Long duration = extras.getLong("duration");
```

Comment: Perfect :) I guess it's time to dust off this project and see if I can get it going again!