# How to get current playing song name in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616956/how-to-get-current-playing-song-details-from-mediaplayer), the song's artist, album, track can be retrieved from a `BroadcastReceiver`, but the song's information which are current playing in Spotify or Pandora cannot be retrieved.(Maybe because these apps don't send broadcast while playing songs).

My question is, how to get current playing song's information on system level, no matter whether the app is broadcasting.

Comment: consider this: you can write a music player that does not provide the rest of the system with any information at all regarding what you are playing. The same goes for other app. There is nothing mandatory or automatic in music player broadcasting their current track information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listening for com.android.music.* broadcasts is the official way to do this on Android.
Many apps like lyrics displayers rely on it to get info on the current track.
Sadly, if the app is not broadcasting the solution is either to have a look at their Dev documentation in case they provide another way to do this or directly ask them to implement it.

For Spotify, it looks like right now they use a 'com.spotify.music.metadatachanged' broadcast (and a settings in the app). You will have to track down separate cases like this one, nothing forces Android devs to implement the standard broadcast.

Comment: you can try Google Music if you want a sample of an app that implements this correctly.

Comment: I've tried Google Music and Amazon Music app, using BroadcastReveiver works fine. However apps like Spotify and Pandora, I can't get song information through that, the BroadcastReceiver got nothing.

Comment: Is there a sample for it?

Answer (score 1):

In android 4.4+, you can use the RemoteController class to get track information from the current playing song. This works with every app that implements a RemoteControlClient. It also works with video- and streamservices like chromecast.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48702254#post48702254

This is a very handy guide if you want to use this RemoteController.

And the developers page:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html

Comment: Is there perhaps a nice tutorial and sample of how to use it? Seems this one lost its samples...

Answer (score 1):

definitely u know the path of the song where is running 
Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse(path);

now u can call this method having the path then we can get all information either in the activity or from the service by binding

```
private void getTrackInfo(Uri audioFileUri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever= new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(getRealPathFromURI(audioFileUri));
    String artist = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    String title = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

} 


private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    File myFile = new File(uri.getPath().toString());
    String s = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: How can I register to such an event though? of "now-playing-this-song" and "now-stopped-playing" ?